# Can not read property "mentions" of undefined, can not read property "guild" of undefined | Discord.js slash commands

Tags: discord.js

So I've tried using slash commands for my discord bot, I've copied and changed around a little bit of the warn command from the old bot where the warn command worked without the slash commands.

My code is

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const mongo = require('../mongo')
const warnSchema = require('../schemas/warn-schema')
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
  slash: 'both',
  testOnly: true,
  minArgs: 2,
  expectedArgs: '<mention> <reason>',
  description: "warns mentioned user",
  callback: async ({ message, args }) => {

const [mention, reason] = args

      const target = message.mentions.users.first()

 

    const guildId = message.guild.id
    const userId = target.id
    

    const warning = {
      author: message.member.user.tag,
      timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
      reason,
    }

const yerz = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('yes')

    await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
      try {
        await warnSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            guildId,
            userId,
          },
          {
            guildId,
            $push: {
              warnings: warning,
            },
          },
          {
            upsert: true,
          }
        )
      } finally {
        mongoose.connection.close()
      }
    })

    return yerz
  },
}
```

If anyone knows how I could make the bot find the guid id and read the mentions, help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you call the `callback` function?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, you export an object with a `callback` method and you call it somewhere and it seems you don't pass the correct arguments.

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Comment: I've got no idea. I've already asked how you used that `callback` but you haven't shown us anything.

Comment: Callback works in the same way execute would work

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your JS code:

```
callback: async ({ message, args }) => {
```

It should be:

```
callback: async ({ message, args }) {
```

Without the `=>` because => and {} are mutually exclusive in this case.

If that does not fix it, it is probably with the line:

```
const [mention, reason] = args
```

Could you tell us what args is? I am guessing its an object but I am not sure.